# Rendering an SVG element from NodeJS in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, svg

I'm trying to render an svg image based on the request sent to the API. The API then responds with a .svg file that I'm trying to render in my application. Adding the file as an element in react doesn't seem to work. I'm using create-react-app and statically imported svg files work fine. This is what my code looks like:

```
const preview = fetch('route to the file')
  .then((res) => res)

return pug`
    div.creator__preview {preview}
`
```

I think it's important to note that for some reason not using pug gives me an error, but I'm guessing that it's just some mistake that I have paid attention to. I have also tried fetching the same URL with postman and it works perfectly fine.

Edit:
It tried using dangerouslySetInnerHTML , but it gives an error saying:
`props.dangerouslySetInnerHTML` must be in the form `{__html: ...}`

this is my code so far:

```
const preview = fetch(
        'route to the file',
    ).then((res) => {
        return {
            __html : res,
        }
    })

return pug`
    div.creator__preview(dangerouslySetInnerHTML={preview})
`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml 
to paste your code in react:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}
```

Be careful with that though. If you don't trust that server 100% you better not to use that function or do some security check

Comment: I tried that and I think it fixed the main issue, but I'm getting an error that says it should be an object that has a field named __html. I named it that but it's still not working. Is there any specific way of returning that I should be aware of? I updated my code above.